# How can i copy a set of s3 keys and copy them into a glacier vault?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-glacier

I am removing objects from s3 and invalidating them in cloudfront. 
I'd like to take those object keys and have s3 copy and  put them into a glacier vault for backups.

is there a way to do this so my client doesn't hold the objects in memory? I have the code running in lambda at the moment.

I don't see any information on if the objects will be copied into memory first or not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to keep some objects, but store them in a low-cost manner.

Amazon Glacier is good for storing large archive files, but is not optimal for storing individual files/objects. Instead, simply **change the storage class in Amazon S3** to `Glacier` or `Glacier Deep Archive`.

Amazon S3 will continue to 'manage' the objects (so they will appear in an S3 bucket), but the actual data will be moved to Glacier. When you wish to retrieve the objects, they can be restored and then accessed through Amazon S3.

This will be *much* simpler than moving objects to the actual Glacier service.

See:

- [Amazon S3 Storage Classes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html)
- For pricing details, see: [Amazon S3 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Comment: I need them to also become inaccessible so cloud front does not cache them again.  I may try and move them to a specific bucket with just our glacier objects.